# How to Deploy Django project on amazon AWS or other server

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, deployment, amazon-ec2

I am digging arround from some days and i can not figure out how to deploy a Django Project.

I have a Amazon AWS EC2 machine running.

I started the project on my laptop, then i configured and installed `Virtualenv` on AWS EC2 and all the requeriments.

This machine has `Apache2` and `libapache2-mod-wsgi` and `mysql` installed.

When i do the command `python manage.py runserver` there are NO errors! I did the `syncdb` and everything is ok.

But a can not see the page in my browser.

Apache config:

```html
File: /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/test_site.com.conf

WSGIScriptAlias / /home/ubuntu/server/workspace/proj/proj/wsgi.py
WSGIPythonPath /home/ubuntu/server/workspace/proj/
<Directory /home/ubuntu/server/workspace/proj/proj>
    <Files wsgi.py>
        Order deny,allow
        Require all granted
    </Files>
</Directory>


Alias /static/ /home/ubuntu/server/workspace/proj/static/

<Directory /home/ubuntu/server/workspace/proj/static>
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

How can i Deploy my Django?

Thanks,
Ricardo

Comment: Any specific reason on trying to deploy on ec2 rather than using something like Elastic Beanstalk? Will be much easier with latter.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to solve my problem.

For new comers, with a similar problem, take a look at this page [Deploy django in Apacha2 server and mod wsgi](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this script that I wrote:
[Safely deploy your Django app in less 1 minute!](https://medium.com/@yask123/safely-deploy-your-django-app-in-less-1-minute-c1d67faad628)

**Instructions**

Installing the DeployDjango script

```
$ wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/yask123/DeployDjango/master/deploydjango.sh && chmod +x deploydjango.sh
```

From your Django App’s root directory (Where manage.py file exists).

```
$ sudo ./deploydjango.sh project_name
```

Done!

*Visit http://ip-address-of-your-instance to see your web app live!*